# What exactly does upgrading the "Venom" augment of Caustic Quills do?

Tags: spiral-knights

I want to start spending skill points on my Maskeraith, but I don't quite understand my options.

```
Focus: Reduces skill cooldown.
Venom: Increases potency of the poison inflicted.
Bristle: Increases the number of quills fired and their sticking duration.
```

What does increasing the potency of the poison inflicted do, exactly?  Does it increase the odds of the enemy being poisoned?  Damage taken?  Time poisoned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Potency refers to how long your enemy targets will stay poisoned.

Upgrading Venom will allow your Maserkaith's quills to poison the targets for a longer duration.

Comment: Okay.  So when Bristle mentions "their sticking duration", does that refer to a DOT while the poison acts as a separate effect?  I think that was where my confusion came from, the way it is worded makes it a little ambiguous.

Comment: Try checking again with the tutorials.  The Quills all explode after a certain period of time.  The more quills you send out and stick to the enemy, the more damage you can do as well as the higher chance of poisoning